# How to detect media file changes(Create/delete) instantly in android for mediaplayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, fileobserver

How to make an android app to listen to media file changes(Create/Delete) like Google Play Music app. 
How Play music app detect file changes while running and how it update the media list instantly.
I have tried FileObserver but never worked.

Is there any sample code for this functionality...??